# Missing leading zeros/date issue in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I have a page where I CREATE and UPDATE an event and this event can have `eventDate` input calendar:

When creating an event all works great. When I update an event I pre-populate this field with the date from DB:

```
txtEventDate.Text = Reader.GetDateTime(7).Date.ToShortDateString();
```

Now, it shows nice:

> 05/05/2011

but **the same code** which worked for CREATING an event, now fails on UPDATING here:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("?eventDate", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.ParseExact(txtEventDate.Text + " " + txtEventTime.Text,
                    "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

because it 'sees' (checked with Debug) that txtEventDate.Text has value:

> 5/5/2011

So the 0's are missing...

It's just really ugly...because in UI they are there...Do you know what can be the problem?

**UPDATE**: I've attached the photo to prove the issue...[image]

Ps: **When I do not EDIT the event** (so I do not pre-populate this field but choose choose some date from calendar) all works perfectly...

Comment: What do you mean that it is really ugly because of the formatting or that it's not working because the 0's aren't there in the value being inserted into the database?

Comment: I wish I had your ugly issues.

Comment: @msarchet - it's ugly that in UI the 0's are there but it fails giving formatting exception and checking with debug I've noticed they are missing... that's why is so strange..

Comment: So, is that txtEventDate's value or the value of txtEventDate.Text?

Comment: Have you tried TryParse just to see if you're getting an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, for date part of a format you should specify `"mm/dd/yyyy"` (with non-capital "M" letters) to ignore the leading zeroes while parsing but my concern is that the error you posted in the image does not include time and you used `DateTime.ParseExact()` function with time format included.

Comment: This was also a good point, and also, another problem was that I have pre-populated with initial data for each post back. now it's solved.